# Re-publish video stream as streaming FLV

Tags: c#, video-streaming

A client of ours has a mobile web cam placed in a forest that is streaming video on a public IP address. Since the web cam has a limited bandwidth (and it is streaming with a format that often requires clients to install a codec), the stream needs to be re-broadcast by a server on a landline, preferably as streaming FLV.

What components can be used to write a client/server that can do this? It would be written using C#.

(Software solutions would be fine too, but we're on a limited budget so it can't be something very expensive...)

Comment: Conceptually, read stream from IP, decode, encode, write to stream to flv? The part there that seems hardest to solve is the "stream to flv" portion, of whihc I'm unsure of the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the format that the camera is sending you?

Rebroadcasting is easy using off-the-shelf servers - which means no programming as such, no C#.

camera -> ffserver -> flash players

[ffserver](http://ffmpeg.org/ffserver-doc.html) is part of [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).